# Use reflection to get actual value of the property notified by INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, reflection, inotifypropertychanged

I am working on a project that will use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to announce property changes to subscriber classes.

```
void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Quantity")
....
```

It appears to me that when the subscribing class receives the notification, the only available value it can get is the name of the property. Is there a way to get a reference of the actual object that has the property change? Then I can get the new value of this property from the reference. Maybe using reflection?

Would anyone mind writing a code snippet to help me out? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sender` might be the one.

Comment: Why not simply extend PropertyChangedEventArgs to also carry the value you are interested in? You can make the extending class generic.

Comment: @slugster: this makes sense only when subscribers know about custom `PropertyChangedEventArgs` descendants. For example, binding engines are not such ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actual object is `sender` (at least, it should be):

```
void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var propertyValue = sender.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(sender);
}
```

If you care about performance, then cache `sender.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName)` results.

Answer (score 10):

Note: this interface is primarily a data-binding API, and data-binding is not limited to simple models like reflection. As such, I would suggest you use the TypeDescriptor API. This will allow you to correctly detect changes for both simple and complex models:

```
var prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(sender)[e.PropertyName];
if(prop != null) {
    object val = prop.GetValue(sender);
    //...
}
```

(with a `using System.ComponentModel;` directive)